# How to draw Circle on Empty Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, android-drawable

I wants to draw Circle on empty canvas, but not getting how to do.
This is code I'm using to create Empty canvas inside my custom ImageView class.

```
bmpBase = Bitmap.createBitmap(image_width, image_height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(bmpBase);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 30, paint);
```

Comment: But by using this code not able to draw circle.

Comment: or If any one can suggest me how to create layered canvas, will be more helpful for me.

Comment: If you're trying to draw the circle on the ImageView itself, call the `drawCircle()` method on the Canvas passed into the ImageView's `onDraw()` method.

Comment: Any chance have you tried: paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

Comment: Mike I don't want to use onDraw(Canvas) wants to make my own canvas and draw circle on to this.

Comment: hey Mike and PrivatMamtora is there a way to create layered canvas ????

Answer (score 3):

try this, in your MainActivity first find your imageView and then:

```
                drawingImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.DrawingImageView);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.BLUE));
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(15);    
                bmpBase = Bitmap.createBitmap(image_width, image_height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 30, paint);
                drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks mmlooloo, but If i'll use this code draw circle by base canvas get hide.This is I want. Canvas c1 = new Canvas(); Canvas c2 = new Canvas(); So on c1 I wants to draw color and few Images and on c2 I wants to place image which will get refreshed time to time. So I don't want to touch my c1 which already has few content and wants to refresh always c2. how to do this?

Comment: how can i understand these assumptions from your question? this is completely new question. i must go out now, but i think you can use background for static part and bitmap with transparent background for non static if you want to get help quickly  ask your question. i think my answer to your question is correct and you should accept it if you consider just your `question assumption`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

You need to set the Paint style to stroke if you just want an outline with no fill:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

and if you want filled circle then:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
```

Or you can refer this:
http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2012/04/draw-circle-on-canvas-canvasdrawcirclet.html

Comment: Thanks Krupa but its not helpful for me.

Comment: Other than this what you want??

Comment: This is I want.     Canvas c1 = new Canvas(); Canvas c2 = new Canvas(); So on c1 I wants to draw color and few Images and on c2 I wants to place image which will get refreshed time to time. So I don't want to touch my c1 which already has few content and wants to refresh always c2. how to do this?